# One time vs Iteration Model in vowpal wabbit with --lrq option

Tags: machine-learning, quadratic, vowpalwabbit, matrix-factorization, quadratic-probing

I am using vowpal wabbit logistic regression with Low Rank Quadratic options (--lrq ) for CTR prediction.I have trained model with two scenario

1. Model building in one time with command

`vw -d  traning_data_all.vw --lrq ic2  --link logistic  --loss_function logistic --l2 0.0000000360911 --l1 0.00000000103629  --learning_rate 0.3 --holdout_off  -b 28 --noconstant  -f final_model`

2. I have breaks the training data in 20 chunks(day wise) and building the model iterative way (with option -i and --save_resume).

first step:-

`vw -d  traning_data_day_1.vw --lrq ic2  --link logistic  --loss_function logistic --l2 0.0000000360911 --l1 0.00000000103629  --learning_rate 0.3 --holdout_off  -b 28 --noconstant  -f model_1`

And then

```
`vw -d  traning_data_day_2.vw --lrq ic2  --link logistic  --loss_function logistic --l2 0.0000000360911 --l1 0.00000000103629  --learning_rate 0.3 --holdout_off  -b 28 --noconstant  --save_resume -i model_1 -f model_2`
```

And so on up to 20 iteration

1st scenario is working fine but in second scenario predictions are tending to 1 OR 0 (only ) after 7-8 iteration. I need 2nd scenario working because i want to update model frequently. l1, l2 and learning_rate are optimised by vw-hypersearch script.

please help me how to solve this issue. Am i missing something ?. I have tried with option `--lrqdropout.`

Comment: `--save_resume` is missing in the first step.

Comment: @MartinPopel  I have tried with --save_resume option in first step but all probabilities are tending to 1 or 0 .